# Compositum of solvable extensions

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, solvable-groups

i have a question on solvable extensions.

I am reading a paper where the authors work with the field $\mathbb{Q}^{solve}$, that is, the maximal solvable extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. I am not sure on what is the definition of this field, but my guess is that is the compositum of all solvable extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$. However, i am not so sure if the compositum of two solvable extensions is still solvable.

Is this true? If not, do you have a counterexample?

Thanks!

Comment: Solvable Galois Compositum, yes

Comment: How do you prove it? I mean, if $E/\mathbb{Q}$ and $F/\mathbb{Q}$ are two solvable extensions, there is $M/E$ such that $M/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois and solvable, and $K/F$ such that $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is also Galois solvable. It is clear then that $MK/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois, but why the Galois group is solvable?

Comment: Galois group of compositum is related to direct product of individual factors

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Note that solvable extensions form a distinguished class of field extensions.

Now look at the set :

$ \mathbb{S}$  = { x $\in \mathbb{C} $ : x is algebraic and the Galois Group of $ {min}_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ is solvable }